# Passing function with defaults as argument ignoring them

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I need to convert a string that represents a vector of `T`s into the corresponding vector.

My problem is that I'd like to pass a simple argument: the converter function. Here's the `split`:

```
template <class T>
auto split(const std::string &s, const std::function<T(const std::string&)> &convert, char sep = ',') -> std::vector<T>
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::vector<T> result;

    while (ss.good())
    {
        std::string substr;
        std::getline(ss, substr, sep);
        if (!substr.empty())
            result.push_back(convert(substr));
    }
    return result;
};
```

It fails to compile when passing standard functions such as `std::stoi` because of the default parameters of `std::stoi` as its signature is `int stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10);`:

```
auto q = split<int>(subs, std::stoi);

error: no matching function for call to 'split'
            auto q = split<int>(subs, std::stoi);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

And obviously I can trick the compiler by using a lambda function:

```
auto q = split<std::size_t>(subs, [](const std::string &s){ return std::stoul(s); });
```

Is there a metaprogramming trick that allows me to somehow *ignore* the default parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by default parameters? You explicitly specified that you want `split<int>`.

Comment: I mean that `std::stoi`, in fact, has default parameters: the signature is `int stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10);`. I hope to ignore that default signature.

Comment: If you can avoid using std:: function, it will make your life easier. (A templated function parameter would be better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... )
```

This macro lets you take the name of a function and generate a lambda that contains the overloads of it.

```
auto q = split<std::size_t>( subs, OVERLOADS_OF(std::stroul) );
```

which is nice and concise.

Default arguments are only accessible by invoking `()` on the actual name of the function, and the only way to "move the name" into a different context is to stuff it into a lambda as text.

As an aside, there is a [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) proposal by @barry to replace `RETURNS(X)` above with `=> X` for lambdas.  I am unaware of a currently maintained proposal to replace the `OVERLOADS_OF` macro (there was one a while back).

Possibly the [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) reflection proposal would permit you to gain access to the default arguments and overload set of a function name, and fancy metaprogramming would then let you generate `OVERLOADS_OF` without a macro.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This doesn’t actually help in this case. I’m leaving it because it’s useful in some other cases, such as if you had a function which returned something convertible to `T`, but it doesn’t address any of the issues with `stoi`.

---

Don’t explicitly specify the type of the function. Let `convert` be any type; you’ll get an error if you try passing something which cannot be called on a `std::string` or which doesn’t return something convertible to a `T`. There’s no reason to constrain the type beyond that unless you specifically have a reason it needs to be that specific type, and in this case you don’t.

Thus, you can declare your function as

```
template <class T, class F>
auto split(const std::string &s, const F&& convert, char sep = ',') -> std::vector<T>
```

Comment: @Yakk Ugh, yes, overloads. I don’t think SFINAE can really handle that, so I don’t know if it’s even possible to get it to work transparently at the call site without macros, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Not even overloads.  With zero overloads, the passed in function pointer or reference (and it has to resolve to an object to be passed in) won't carry with it the default arguments.  So at point of call it won't work.

Comment: @Yakk You’re right, my answer helps in some circumstances but not this one.